# Looking at Hard-Code used in VS 2012

Tags: c#, function, methods

Just as if you create your own class, and design your functions, and can see the code you use in your functions (or methods), I want to see the code used in the functions that are built into VS 2012. Like the Math.POW, for example  want to see the code being used to make that happen. Or In the Console class, I want to see the code in the functions for WriteLine, Write, etc.

The reason I want to do this is because sometimes with more complicated functions I'm calling or classes I'm using I feel I'm just using tools I don't know how they actually work.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the .NET source code:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Alternatively, use a decompiler such as [JustDecompile.](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

Comment: c# isn't open source, how much of it's code did microsoft released?

Comment: Most of it. The functions you have described in your original post are clearly visible within the download or using a decompiler. I'd suggest you try it out, and then ask if there are any classes that you want to see, that you cannot.

Comment: Nope, good point, :) Also ASP.NET MVC is entirely open source as well. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/ ....for further reference.

Comment: I downloaded the files are the microsoft link you provided. When I click on them they don't really want to load anything... am I missing something?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx  ....

Answer (score 0):

You can view the source via the metadata of the .NET Framework by clicking on the method of interest and pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or right clicking the mouse and choosing `Go To Definition` from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer in my opinion is this site :

[DotNetInside](http://dotnetinside.com/framework/WCF+Data+Services/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/ODataRequestMessageWrapper)

Used it to port some classes to Mono that I probably didn't need to.